# Check If Document Library Already Exists Using Powershell

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, document-library, powershell

How can I perform a check if a document library already exists using Powershell in SharePoint 2010?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Something like this:

```
$w = get-spweb "<webURL>"
$list = $w.Lists.TryGetList("<Title of the list>")
if($list -ne $null)
{
    # The list already exists
}
```

Replace `<webURL>` and `<Title of the list>` with your actual values

Comment: And is there also a way to check that it is a document library type list and not just a normal list?

Comment: On the list you can call `$list.BaseType`. It will return `DocumentLibrary` for libraries and `GenericList` for lists